# Calculation of $df(x)/dg(x)$

Tags: derivatives

How does one calculate $df(x)/dg(x)$ where f and g are two unrelated functions of x?

Comment: What is your definition of $df(x)/dg(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

By the Chain Rule, $\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}\frac{dg(x)}{dx} = \frac{df(x)}{dx}$. Thus, $\boxed{\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)} = \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}}$